# nginx+socket.io+ssl: WebSocket connection to 'ws://wechat.pageguy.tech/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: ssl, express, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I want to configure an node.js project using socket.io through nginx with ssl,But I failed,when I start it an error occours like this:

[image]

I spent a whole noon search and read documents but still can not figure out how to solve this..If anyone meet this problem before or have any idea about it please help me,thanks a lot.

This is my client side js code:

```
let socket = io.connect('//wechat.pageguy.tech/ws', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

This is nginx code:

```
server {
listen       443;
server_name  wechat.pageguy.tech;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/pageguy.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/pageguy.key.unsecure;

location / {
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3335;
}

location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3005;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
}
```

My express port is 3335,my socket.io port is 3005.Everything were fine before I added ssl in the nginx configuration file.

Comment: You are showing the config for ssl but you get the error message from accessing ws://, i.e. not ssl (this would have been wss:// instead). This means that the part of the config you show is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: I tried to using "wss://" instead,but still got same error message.I think the problem is not the schema but the configuration,I just can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody help me 555, but I solved problems by myself.

in client side js code:

```
let socket = io.connect('https//wechat.pageguy.tech/', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

in nginx configure file:

```
location /socket.io/(not /ws/ because its default value)
```